# Java grpc client channel args

Tags: java, grpc, grpc-java

I'm trying to set the channel "arg grpc.http2.min_time_between_pings_ms" from java grpc client side, but cannot find any API for this.

Searched pretty much everywhere - seems like it should be in [ManagedChannelBuilder](https://grpc.github.io/grpc-java/javadoc/index.html?io/grpc/ManagedChannelBuilder.html) as it has keepout args. Does anyone know how this to set this in java?

Comment: ManagedChannelBuilder is the right place to look. grpc java doesn't have this settings available. if you believe grpc java should have this setting, please file an issue on github. btw, why do you need this setting? or, what blocks you to use existing keepalive?

Answer (score 0):

Is `ManagedChannelBuilder#keepAliveTimeout(...)` the thing you are looking for?